# Unable to load infinite page in selenum using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to scrape justdial website data and it doesn't have pagenumbers instead it have infinite scrolling.
The page was loaded initially (`10 stores`). but when i applied scrolling i have to load more html(`of 100 stores`) content but it doesn't loads the content.

url : https://www.justdial.com/Sangli/Car-Dealers/

**My entire code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
URL = "https://www.justdial.com/Sangli/Car-Dealers/"
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.maximize_window()

# code for infinite page scrolling 
items = []
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
itemTargetCount = 20
time.sleep(10)


while itemTargetCount > len(items):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, (document.body.scrollHeight)*0.60)")
    time.sleep(10)
    wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'resultbox_title_anchor'))
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'resultbox_title_anchor')
    textElements=[]
    for element in elements:
        textElements.append(element.text)
    items = textElements
    print(items)
else:
    print("Done loading")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
stores = soup.find_all('div', class_='resultbox_textbox')
# last three stores tag contain None   
for store in stores[:10]:
    print("Title : ", store.find('a', 'resultbox_title_anchor').text)
    print("Rating : ",store.find('div', 'resultbox_totalrate').text)
    print("Rated By : ", store.find('div', 'resultbox_countrate').text)
    print("Address : ", store.find('div', 'resultbox_address').text)
    print("Tags : " , [amenities.text for amenities in store.find_all('span', 'amenities_tabs')])
    print("COntact : ", store.find('span', 'callcontent').text)
    # print(stores[i].text)
    
    print('\n\n')
print(items)
```

It loads only 10 store details what to do if i want whole 100 store details?

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of issues with this site. I don't know if it's because I'm in the US or what but it timed out or infinitely loaded a lot.

I changed the scrolling approach and simplified things a lot. Rather than worrying about `scrollHeight`, I just scrolled to the second to last desired element on the page. That jumped me far enough down the page in one shot that it started loading the next section of the page.

I've tested this code and it's working. I did not change any of the BeautifulSoup section of the code since this question was only concerning the scrolling portion of your code. The updated code is below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
URL = "https://www.justdial.com/Sangli/Car-Dealers/"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# code for infinite page scrolling 
item_target_count = 20
anchor_locator = (By.CLASS_NAME,'resultbox_title_anchor')
anchors = driver.find_elements(*anchor_locator)

while item_target_count > len(anchors):
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", anchors[-2])
    anchors = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located(anchor_locator))

for e in anchors:
    print(e.text)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
stores = soup.find_all('div', class_='resultbox_textbox')
# last three stores tag contain None   
for store in stores[:10]:
    print("Title : ", store.find('a', 'resultbox_title_anchor').text)
    print("Rating : ",store.find('div', 'resultbox_totalrate').text)
    print("Rated By : ", store.find('div', 'resultbox_countrate').text)
    print("Address : ", store.find('div', 'resultbox_address').text)
    print("Tags : " , [amenities.text for amenities in store.find_all('span', 'amenities_tabs')])
    print("Contact : ", store.find('span', 'callcontent').text)
    # print(stores[i].text)
    
    print('\n\n')
```

Comment: Sir, It's scrolling but i doesn't loads the javascript/html of that extended content .In short it doesn't loads the next content.

Comment: Your code asked it to get 20 items. It's printing the 20 items... those are loaded. Are you talking about something else or ? I'm confused.

Comment: Yeah it's printing the 20 items but sometimes fails. And also when i was extending the loop to print more it fails and the html of that are also not available. But i want the whole html content of the 20 items.

Comment: I had a lot of issues with the site. I don't know if it's because I'm in the US but the page wasn't loading consistently for me. Maybe you're having the same issue. I think it's a site issue. You might just have to run the script a few times to get all the data you want. It might also be that you need some error checking added to your BeautifulSoup section.